# Is there an R function/package for determining WWF biomes from latlong coordinates?

Tags: r, dataset, latitude-longitude, r-package

Very new here, hi, postgraduate student who is tearing their hair out.

I have inherited a dataset of secondary data collected from research papers on species populations and their genetic diversity and have been adding more appropriate data to this sheet in preparation to perform some analyses. Part of the analysis will include subsetting the data by biome type to create comparisons between the biomes, and therefore I've been cleaning up and trying at add this information to the data I've added. I have latlong coordinates for each population (in degrees decimals) and it appears that the person working on this before me was able to use these to determine the biome for each point, specifically following the Olson et al. (2001)/WWF 14 biome categorisation, but at this point I'll take anything.

However I have no idea how this was achieved and truly can't find anything to help. After googling just about every combination of "r package biomes WWF latitude longitude species assign derive convert" that you can think of, the only packages that I have located are non functioning in my version of RStudio (e.g. biomeara, ggbiome), leaving me with no idea if they'd even work, and all other pages that I have dragged up seem to already have biome data included with their dataset. Other research papers I have found describe assigning biomes based on latlong coords and give 0 steps on how to actually achieve this. Is it possible in R? Am I losing my mind? Does anyone know of a way to do this, whether in R or not, and that preferably doesn't take forever as I have over 8000 populations to assess? Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe try posting your problem on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Nobody in bioinformatics will be able to help, but someone at `r-sig-ecology@r-project.org` might help.

Comment: Have you tried asking for the WWF biome polygons to some of the paper authors (in some spatial format like shp)? Having the polygon it is pretty easy to compute the process.